# Firebase store provider photo URL (cannot convert value of type NSURL?)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I am new to Firebase and I want to store the provider photo URL however it come out the error 'Can only store objects of type NSNumber, NSString, NSDictionary, and NSArray.' I have tried different type of the method but it seems not working for example `let profilePicUrl = profile.photoURL as String` or `let profilePicUrl = NSString(NSURL: profile.photoURL)`

It is my method

```
func createFirebaseUser(){

        let key = ref.child("user").childByAutoId().key
        if let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser{
            for profile in user.providerData{
                let uid = profile.uid
                let providerID = profile.providerID
                let displayName = profile.displayName
                let email = ""
                let profilePicUrl = profile.photoURL


                //let userDict :[String : AnyObject] = ["name": username!"profilePicUrl": profilePicUrl!]
            let profile = Profile(uid: uid, displayName: displayName!,email: email, imageUrl: profilePicUrl)

                let childUpdates = ["/user/\(key)": profile]


                ref.updateChildValues(childUpdates, withCompletionBlock: { (error, ref) -> Void in
                    // now users exist in the database
                    print("user stored in firebase")
                })
            }
        }
```

and it is the data model

```
import Foundation

class Profile {

private var _uid: String
private var _displayName: String
private var _email: String?
private var _gender: String!
private var _city: String!
private var _imageUrl: String!

var uid: String {
    return _uid
}

var displayName: String {
    get {
        return _displayName
    }

    set {
        _displayName = newValue
    }
}

var email: String {
    get {
        return _email!
    }

    set {
        _email = newValue
    }
}

var gender: String {
    get {
        return _gender
    }

    set {
        _gender = newValue
    }
}

var city: String {
    get {
        return _city
    }

    set {
        _city = newValue
    }
}

var imageUrl: String {
    get {
        return _imageUrl
    }

    set {
        _imageUrl = newValue
    }
}

init(uid: String, displayName: String, email: String, imageUrl: String) {
    _uid = uid
    _displayName = displayName
    _email = email
    _imageUrl = imageUrl

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only store the 4 types of NSObjects you mentioned in Firebase. But for the most part, data is just a string and storing strings is easy.

Assuming that your photoURL is an actual NSURL, you can save it as a string

```
let ref = myRootRef.childByAppendingPath("photo_urls")
let thisFileRef = ref.childByAutoId()
thisFileRef.setValue(photoURL.absoluteString)
```

and to go from a string to an NSURL

```
let url = NSURL(string: urlString)!
```

Also, it appears you a creating a new user in Firebase. You can greatly simplify your code like this

```
let usersRef = self.myRootRef.childByAppendingPath("users")
let thisUserRef = usersRef.childByAutoId()

var dict = [String: String]()
dict["displayName"] = "Bill"
dict["email"] = "bill@thing.com"
dict["gender"] = "male"
dict["photo_url"] = photoURL.absoluteString

thisUserRef.setValue(dict)
```

I would suggest making that code part of your User class so you can

```
let aUser = User()
aUser.initWithStuff(displayName, email, gender etc etc
aUser.createUser()
```

That really reduces the amount of code and keeps it clean.

If you are storing users, you should use the auth.uid as the key to each users node. This is more challenging in v3.x than it was in 2.x but hopefully Firebase will soon have a fix.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. If I would like to fetch the data from `FIRAuth.auth().currentuser`. Do i need to change the data dict to `provider.email` etc instead of the specifc data?

Comment: Not sure I understand that question but currentUser will have a unique ID, a primary email address, a name and a photo URL. So if you need to query for an email, then you would also want to store it within the /users/uid node because you cannot search for it otherwise. So in my example, it was just a generic email placeholder - maybe a second email but you could easily include whatever you want

Answer (score 1):

What you should really do is to store a relative path to your data into Firebase database and the prefix of the absolute URL separately (maybe in Firebase in some other node or somewhere else). This will help you to be flexible and being able to switch to a different storage without a lot of worries. Moreover, it should solve your current problem, because you will be storing raw strings in the Firebase and then in the app, you will merge prefix and the relative path together in order to produce the complete URL.

For example, let's assume that your URL to a photo looks like that:

http://storage.example.com/photos/photo1.jpg

Then, you can decompose this URL into:

```
prefix = http://storage.example.com/
relativeUrl = photos/photo1.jpg
```

And store the prefix for example in some settings node in the Firebase database and the relativeUrl in your photos' data.

Then in order to construct the complete URL you want to concatenate them together.

Comment: but the photo is from `provider.photoURL` which means i fetch the url from the login provider how could i do it from your answer?